# Is Pear OS 8 Updating possible?

Tags: updates

So I was able to get my hands on a copy of Pear OS 8. I just want to know if it can update to Ubuntu 14.04 while still having the same UI. I'm pretty sure it runs 13.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update from Pear to Ubuntu. You can only remove Pear and install Ubuntu over it.

As for User interface Ubuntu uses different interface, but you can customize it with a Pear / Mac look after installing. You may use **Cairo-Dock** software for this.

[image: *Cairo SCreenshot*]

Comment: Alright thank you. Just thought it was possible since Pear OS is built on top of Ubuntu.